# Angular Tests always fail on $logProvider when getting constants in tests

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

Very new to Angular testing... using 1.3.0.rc0. To get started I'm trying to do something simple: get the value of a constant I set. Within a config.js, I have the following:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('app');

    // create app configuration
    var appConfig = {
        version = '0.0.1.0',
        debugMode = true
    };

    app.constant('config', appConfig);

    app.config([function ($logProvider, config) {
            // set the debugging setting of the app > same setting for the app
            if ($logProvider.debugEnabled) {
                $logProvider.debugEnabled(config.debugMode);
            }
        }]);
})();
```

I'm tried numerous things to write my tests (using jasmine & karma), but I keep getting an error that:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to: 
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$logProvider.debugEnabled').
```

I get that this was a bug a while ago in the angular-mocks.js file but has since been resolved. Regardless, no matter the test I write, it doesn't work. Here's what i'm working with now, knowing that there are issues with it.

```
'use strict';
describe('config.js', function () {
    var logProvider;

    beforeEach(module(inject(function ($log) {
        logProvider = $log;
    })));
    beforeEach(module('app', logProvider));

    it('should set the config constant to the app global configuration settings', function () {
        var $injector = angular.injector(['ng', 'app']);
        var settings = $injector.get('config');
        //var settings = inject(config);
        expect(settings.debugMode).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

Am I doing this right? If so, is there no way to get around the test issue with $logProvider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is much to learn about how modules work in Angular, especially under testing with ngMocks. I'll try to be brief.

One always begins by calling `module` (from ngMocks) one (or more times) to build up the module "cookbook" for a test run.

In any of these `module` calls you have an opportunity to access and stash away a previously defined provider.

The first time you call `inject` (from ngMocks) in a given test path, the module "cookbook" is "baked" for that path and the injector is populated based on recipes in that "cookbook".

Subsequent calls to `module` are irrelevant. Your expression `beforeEach(module('app', logProvider));` executes too late (even if it did what you wanted, which it would not).

> In fact, I'm surprised that you didn't get the error: "*Error: Injector already created, can not register a module!*".

`inject` always returns the thing created by the provider, never the provider itself. Your first `beforeEach` ...

```
beforeEach(module(inject(function ($log) {
    logProvider = $log;
})));
```

... actually sets `logProvider` to the `$log` service, not the `$logProvider`.

## Does this help?

Here is a sample from my forthcoming course on Ng testing that shows how to access a provider (in this case, the $logProvider). It was inspired by your question.

First, the `config2` constant (I already had a value called `config`:

```
// my sample application module definition is called 'basics'
var basics = angular.module('basics', []);

/* define 'config2' constant - which is available in Ng's config phase */
basics.constant('config2', {
    debugMode:  true
});

// use constant in config phase
basics.config(function ($logProvider, config2) {
    $logProvider.debugEnabled(config2.debugMode);
})
```

Now the spec (using Mocha and Chai):

```
describe('Basics - constant:', function() {
    'use strict';

    beforeEach(module('basics'));

    // other stuff
    
    describe("the $logProvider", function(){
        var configConstant;
        var $log;
        var $logProvider;

        beforeEach(module(
            // Could combine with module('basics') definition in outer describe
            // but only need it here in this describe

            // This module definition function has access to any previously defined provider
            // which in this case is any provider defined in ng, ngMocks, or basics
            function( _$logProvider_) {
                $logProvider = _$logProvider_;
            }
        ));

        // inject triggers injector creation; module definition now "baked"
        beforeEach(inject(function(config2, _$log_){
            configConstant = config2;
            $log = _$log_;
        }));

        it("is accessible via the module function", function(){
            expect($logProvider).to.exist;
        });

        it("is not the same as the log service", function(){
            expect($logProvider).not.to.equal($log);
        });

        it("has same debugEnabled value as config2.debugMode", function(){
            expect($logProvider.debugEnabled()).to.equal(configConstant.debugMode);
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: BAM... this nailed it. My problem was (1) understanding how the inject worked, (2) how beforeEach() worked with modules and (3) that in the source file the $logProvider wasn't getting correctly injected. I shouldn't have pasted in the $log code... that was in-midst-flailing trying to get it to work. Thanks!!!

Comment: @Ward... I'm very interested in your "...forthcoming course on Ng testing". Any more information available? Thanks!